# Pass a subscribeable Action as parameter

Tags: c#, events, action

I have an event that I need to subscribe a method to within a constructor, so I want to pass the event *(Action OnNewGps)* through like this:

```
public AccelCalculator(SensorManager sensorManager, Action<double, double> OnNewData, Action<GPSReading> OnNewGps)
{
    this.sensorManager = sensorManager;
    sensorManager.OnNewAccelReading += CalibrateAccel;
    OnNewGps += ProcessGPS;
    OnNewDataCalculation += OnNewData;
}
```

The constructor method itself is not giving me any errors, but I am unable to call it from another class, with a reference to the locationManager instance:

```
accelCalculator = new AccelCalculator(sensorManager, RecordAccel, locationManager.OnPositionUpdated );
```

Because:

> The event 'LocationManager.OnPositionUpdated' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=

LocationManager.OnPositionUpdated is defined:

```
public event Action<GPSReading> OnPositionUpdated;
```

Comment: you want to pass an Event (of publisher class)  into constructor (of a subscriber class) where subscriber subscribe it with some local method. and whenever that event is being raised, that method should be called. like that?

Comment: Update your question with the fact that Subscriber in being instantiated in other class (other than Publisher) which do have reference of publisher class.

Answer (score 1):

Two Points which we should keep in our mind.

### First

***you can pass that event in to constructor as argument But only when you are creating an object staying in the scope of class which is holding that event.***

see error message below.

> The event 'PublisherClass.Event' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -= **(except when used from within the type 'PublisherClass')**

this error occurs when you try to raise/pass events staying outside of the class where it was being declared.

So staying inside of the class, **we can raise as well as pass events** as parameter!

So now we know, if we are creating instance of subscriber (calling    subscriber's constructor), we can surely pass Event into constructor. *I have shown this in second half of this answer.*

But that is not good practice of using Events.

Generally (and preferred way), publisher class should never hold an object of Subscriber class. instead subscriber class should hold object of publisher class.

simple reason, if publisher have object of subscriber, it can directly call methods of subscriber (no point of raising events to perform functionalities of subscriber).

### Second

The fact that, in your code you don't have subscriber created in publisher; good for you. but the same fact will restrict you to pass publisher's event into constructor's event.

*Which is required too
        Becuase, if Events are fully accessible out side of the classes
        Any outer call can manipulate it.
        E.G. if an event is subscribed by few subscriber, 
              and some outsider call, assign null to it.
              all it's subscription will be gone.
              We can use concept of encapsulation 
                  to avoid this being done inside of code (no manipulating code should be exposed publicly)*

Best thing you can do is to pass object of publisher into constructor of subscriber, and in subscriber's constructor; you can subscribe your desired event with proper method. like below.

```
public delegate Object EventType();
public class PublisherClass
{
    private event EventType Event;

    public event EventType EventAccessor
    {
        add { Event += value; }
        remove { Event -= value; }
    }

    public void RaiseAnEvent()
    {
        if (Event != null) { Event(); }
    }
}
```

subscriber class,

```
public class SubscriberClass
{
    public SubscriberClass(PublisherClass p)
    {
        p.EventAccessor += d_Event;
    }

    object d_Event()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and the other class where you are creating the object of subscriber and also reference of publisher.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PublisherClass p = new PublisherClass();
        SubscriberClass s = new SubscriberClass(p);
        p.RaiseAnEvent();   
    }
```

---

Here is how you may pass event as parameter **(But not good practice as mentioned above)**

whatever parameter and return type that event must take and return, make a delegate for it.

Suppose you want a method which returns an `object` (here in your case : `Action<GPSReading>`)

`public delegate Object EventType();`

If you subscriber class is being

now in publisher class declare an event of `EventType`

```
public delegate Object EventType();
public class PublisherClass
{
    public event EventType Event;

    public PublisherClass()
    {
        SubscriberClass d2 = new SubscriberClass(ref Event);
        if (Event != null)
        {
            Event();
        }
    }
}
```

Subscriber class

```
public class SubscriberClass
{
    public SubscriberClass(ref EventType eve)
    {
        eve += d_Event;
    }

    object d_Event()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```